# Changing a transparent images background color after clicking on a seperate div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a background color selection to an E-Card site I am making for an assignment in college. 
I have the button and the background set up, but cant seem to get the JS for it to work.
I am a newbie with javascript/jquery, so I'm aware I am probably making a ridiculous mistake, but my code so far is:

```
$(".pink").on("click", function() {
$(".card-preview img").css("background-color", "red");
});
```

Where ".pink" is the button you would press to the the background color of an image inside the "card-preview" div.

This way seems relatively simple, but doesn't seem to be working!
Any ideas/suggestions?

The .pink div has a dual class on it, the second class is ".box", which sets the size as there are a few intended color selections available.

The page in question is linked here: http://www.remotegoatdesign.com/sayhey/pages/edit-valentines-marc-card.html

Comment: Can you add jsfiddle on jsfiddle.net. It would be much easier to debug

Comment: Is it possible that the code is working, but the image is opaque and takes up the full space of its element, so you can't see that its background colour has actually changed? Otherwise, I also feel we need a bit more code from you to diagnose the problem.

Comment: There are a few js files etc linked to the page. I am currently uploading the page via FTP to my server if that would be any help?

Comment: Try to only provide what you feel is directly related to the problem, so we can more easily track down its source.

Comment: Okay I'll put together a fiddle now, should be 20 minutes or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your code to: 
`$(function() {
    $(".pink").on("click", function() {
        $(".card-preview img").css("background-color", "red");
    });
});`
or place on bottom of page, berofe `</body>`

This makes your code run only after the DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

`.card-preview img`: you are changing the background colour of the `img` elements inside the div, not the div itself.

Comment: That's intentional, the image is transparent in the sections I want to change the color in. However I tried changing it in case that was still affecting it, but no difference sadly. :(

Comment: You said you wanted to change the background colour of the div. If that isn't the case, could you correct your question? While you are at it, you should add the HTML you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

try using `.click()` it worked fine for me. check my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adAUU/2/)

### edit

noticed your selection divs for colors show `class='box pink'` i changed my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adAUU/3/) to match.

### edit

for the comment below: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adAUU/4/)

Comment: Note that your JSFiddle is currently set to run JS onLoad - if you set it to "No wrap - in <head>" (which is what the live scenario is), it won't work.